# События Unity | C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, события, input

Как поймать событие Input.GetAxis в Unity?

И, если можно, добавьте ссылку на документацию со всеми имеющимися событиями unity.

Comment: Мне кажется, [`Input.GetAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) это не событие, а метод.

Comment: Это я знаю, но мне нужно событие именно этого метода.

Comment: Лучше просто скажите своими словами, что вы хотите сделать, потому что у методов не бывает событий. Событие это особый вид делегата, а делегат - особый вид метода. `GetAxis()` - обычный метод, и к делегатам никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: Вангую! Хочет совместить работу `Input.GetAxis()` с другим UI аналогом для мобильника, что бы поддержывался и геймпад и тачскрин. И не смотря на то что мобильники стали основная платформа юнити, `Input` не обслуживает `UI` интерфейсы, только `Touchs`. Вот он и хочет понять, когда ловить инпуты с `GetAxis`, а когда с `UI`.

Comment: Нет, не то и не другое. Я хочу ловить нажатие AWSD и запускать соответствуещий метод. Это можно легко сделать в update или fixedUpdate, но я слышал, что есть способ с событиямия, поэтому хотелось его попробовать.

Comment: Если вы слышали о каком-то "способе", то почему бы не воспользоваться тем, что вы услышали? Нет никаких событий, связанных с `GetAxis`. Есть система событий на новой системе ввода, можно написать свое событие, но из коробки такого решения нет.

Comment: Можно самому написать эвенты реагирующие на `Input.GetAxis()`. Объект на сцена смотрящий на оси и статический класс с эвентами `Neutral, Up, Down, Right , Left`. Все.

Comment: А можно использовать новую InputSystem которая может посылать такие ивенты:)

Answer (score 0):

Input.GetAxis возвращает число (текущая скорость на определенной оси), а чтобы это было событием нужно уже это реализовывать вручную. Но вообще все, что касается частого обновления, не очень то хорошо реализовывать через events, а input в особенности (проверено на собственном опыте).

Для кнопки задержка в .1s может и норм, но вот когда пытаешься удрать от врагов и управление работает с небольшой задержкой - это уже неприемлемо. Так что лучше тут воздержаться от использования событий.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял нужно обработать событие от Input.GetAxis и заставить что то выполнять. P.S: пишу с телефона и могут быть ошибки.

```
public  float temp 

void Update()
{
     temp -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

     if(temp>0)
     {
          temp = 0;
         //вызываем что то,  если больше нуля.
      }

      if(temp<0)
      { 
           temp = 0;
           //вызываем что то,  если меньше нуля.
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот тебе событие которое при изменение Input.GetAxis будет передавать значение оси подписчикам

```
public delegate void Axis(float val);
public static event Axis GetAxisX;
public static event Axis GetAxisY;
void Update(){
    float axisX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float axisY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    GetAxisX?.Invoke(axisX);
    GetAxisY?.Invoke(axisY);
}
// В других скриптах где нужно получать данное событие
void OnEnable(){
    yourScriptWithEvent.GetAxisX += AxisX;
    yourScriptWithEvent.GetAxisY += AxisY;
}

private void AxisX(float val){
    //что то делаем с тем значением что получаем
}
private void AxisY(float val){
    //что то делаем с тем значением что получаем
}
void OnDisable(){
    yourScriptWithEvent.GetAxisX -= AxisX;
    yourScriptWithEvent.GetAxisY -= AxisY;
}
```